# SQL Query every second

Tags: c#, mysql, triggers

I am working on a chat application and I need your help.
I store the information, if someone is online in a database. And now I have a feature, which shows your friendlist and if the chatpartner is online. The problem ist: I want to check frequently, if someone goes online. By now I have a SQL Statement timed every second to retrieve the Data and show it on the Client. The problem: The whole application starts lagging and is slowed down (which makes sense). And now I need your help. How can i improve this. I thought about different things. First of all I had the idea to check just every 5 minutes or so, if someone is online. But I don't want to wait 5 minutes, until I see the correct online / offline list. So this opportunity isn't really possible. My next idea was to just retrieve the data, when the Table is updated (because someone goes online). I thought of a trigger, but is it possible to write a trigger, which is invoked on update, but calls a Method in my C# code?
I have really no idea, and I hope you can help me.

What would you recommend for such an application?

Greetings

Comment: Is this a desktop app or a web app?

Comment: And what...each client has its own database?

Comment: No I have a central database, with a user list. And everytime a user starts his application and enters his credentials, the Usertable is updated and the value of the "online" column is updated.

Comment: And the code that accepts the login and updates the user status...it can't simply trigger its own event to say "user is online"?

Comment: The problem is: Every user has its own client. 

User 1 starts up his program: he goes online, and user 2 is his friend who is currently offline.
So now user 2 goes online, and how should I update the status of user 2 in user 1's friendlist? Both programs run on different machines. (Thats the reason, why I store the status in the database)

Comment: You appear to be exposing the database too much; clients should almost never have direct access to the DB.  Instead, you should have a chat server somewhere that the clients connect to.  That server would accept logins, and would tell the other connected clients that someone just logged in.  It'd already have a list of online users, so that info would not need to be recorded in the DB.

Comment: Yep, I know... But I do not have the possibility to set up a server on which everyone conects. (And that's why I have this problem :D )
And although a client should just have minimum acces to the databse I try it like that. (Because of my limited capabilities)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Your structure is simply not scalable.  In fact, whenever your architecture has client programs polling a central server, you should be thinking "this is a potential scalability problem".  If they are downloading yesterday's results once per day, that may be ok.  Once per second -- your server is simply going to be responding to these requests.

The solution is that when someone comes online or offline, then have the *server* contact that relevant clients.  There are at least two ways to do this.  The "built-into-the-database" method is to have a trigger.  I am not fond of using triggers for this purpose, because this type of logic can create cumbersome and difficult to find dependencies.

Instead, I prefer to wrap operations like "user logging in now" and "user logging out now" into stored procedures.  This stored procedure would update the relevant tables and notify the relevant clients that friend are available.

Of course, this means that your client has to be able to handle asynchronous messages from the server.  That is one of capabilities needed for a truly scalable system.

Comment: Seems logical. 
Only problem: I have no server. I have just the clients, and the databse.

Comment: @capekall . . . You *do* have a server.  It is the database server.  You should communicate to the database through an API consisting of stored procedures rather than direct calls to `insert`/`update`/`delete` statements.

Comment: Well, but how am I able to contact the clients in a stored procedure? 
I could do the update, etc. in a stored procedure. But I still need to poll the Database, to retrieve the actual online list.

Comment: @capekall . . . Well that is the challenge.  That requires storing connection information in the database.  You might need an actual server process to make this scalable.

Comment: Yep, if I had a server for the chat itself it would be way easier. But I don't.

I read something about SqlDependency for C#, which would be great I think. Because it monitors the database, and if a specific query is executed it runs a method. But it only works with Ms SQL. 
Is there something like SqlDependency for My SQL?